# Zimbra installation missing spamassassin folder

Tags: razor-2, zimbra, spamassassin

I have a relatively new Zimbra installation. It is version 8.6.0_GA_1153.FOSS. I was trying to enable Razor using the instructions here: http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Improving_Anti-spam_system. Unfortunately, the entire spamassassin folder seems to be missing from /opt/zimbra/conf. Is it in another location in this version of Zimbra? Do I need to take a prerequisite step?

Answer (score 0):

On this zimbra release you need a patch to be a least a level 1178

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was busy on other projects, and I just got back to this. I installed the patch, and I'm now at 1178. I still don't have the spamassassin folder.